# Convert an array of c# Model Date property to JSON Date value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C# model which I return to my view, I then convert this to an array of JSON objects like so:

```
@{
    string data = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}
var modelData = @Html.Raw(data);
```

My Model looks like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public decimal Value { get; set; }
```

When I output the `Date` it gets output as: `Date: /Date(1338279123847)/`

Is there anyway I can convert the date to a Javascript date before outputting it on my view, perhaps from within my `modelData` array? In the form of `DD/MM/YYYY`

Comment: Is that date copied directly from your code's output? I'm unsure of it's format. I originally though it was a epoch timestamp, but unless the date was originally sometime in May 44,378, I don't think it is.

Comment: The Date property in my C# Model is just today's date: `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that while serializing the model but you could do it afterwards:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modelData = {"Date":"\/Date(1338279675925)\/"};
    var jsDate = new Date(parseInt(modelData.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
    alert(jsDate.toISOString());
</script>
```

Another possibility is to use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) which allows you to [serialize dates using ISO 8601 format](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx) instead of the built-in `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: But `modelData` also contains other properties, is it possible to use JQuery.each method perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand what does the fact that your modelData contains other properties has to do with dates serialization.

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer to solve it, also used JQuery.each() function: `var modelData = @Html.Raw(data);` And then:
`modelData = $.each(modelData, function(i, v) {
var dateString = new Date(parseInt(v.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
v.Date = dateString.getDate() + "/" + (dateString.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateString.getFullYear();
});`

Comment: And you really should consider switching to JSON.NET. It's faster than JavaScriptSerializer and more powerful. And Scott Hanselman approves this message! ;) http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: Completely agree with lucask. Json.NET will be the default serializer anyway in future ASP.NET MVC versions so why not start using it right now? This way you will have one less thing to worry about when you migrate your application.

Comment: have a look at this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx some good ideas on Serialising Dates to JSON